# Referring the class that extends this class in a function

Tags: kotlin

https://pl.kotl.in/WJxo0DujU (below is the code in the link)

```
open class A() { }

class B(): A() { 
   fun pew2() { }
}

fun <a: A> a.pew() = apply { }

fun main() {
    val b = B()
    b.pew().pew2()
}
```

Is there a way to have the function `pew()` in class A (not in A's companion object) and still be able to type `b.pew().pew2()` (not `b.apply { pew().pew2() }`)?

Comment: You mean "not `b.apply { pew() }.pew2()`", right?

Answer (score 1):

You could create the `pew()` method in `A` and have the method return the instance itself:

```kotlin
open class A() { 
    fun pew() = this 
}

class B(): A() {
    fun pew2() { }
}

fun main() {
    val b = (B().pew() as B).pew2()
}
```

Comment: @rtsketo, did this help? Let me know if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the function in B and narrow the return type.

```
open class A() { 
    open fun pew(): A {
        //...
        return this
    }
}

class B: A() { 
    fun pew2() { } 
    override fun pew(): B {
        super.pew()
        return this
    }
}
```

Kotlin doesn't have a `self` type that would make these kinds of chainable functions easier to implement, but the `apply` function makes chainable functions that return the same object unnecessary.